# Error with this.id in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Ok, so I'm using JS and I am having issues with the following function.

In my PHP file I have:

```
<?php

    $file = fopen("utensils/".$cake.".txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");

    while(!feof($file)) {
            $image = fgets($file);
            echo "<div id='".$image."' class='utensil' onclick='useUtensil(this.id)'>".$image."</div>";
    }

    fclose($file);

 ?>
```

whilst in the JS I have:

```
function useUtensil(id) {
        alert(id);
    if (id == "Sandwich Tins") {    
        alert(id);
    } else {
        alert("You do not need that utility!");
    }
}
```

It's a very strange bug since I have a practically identical piece of code which works, however, with this code, although the first alert(id) alerts "Sandwich Tins", it does not alert(id), instead running into the else statement.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: An id may not contain a space ...

Comment: Tried it with it not using spaces and it still didn't work,  my other one which works also uses spaces...

Comment: Learn to debug, what is passed in as the id? console.log is your friend.

Comment: What is passed in as the id is "Sandwich Tins", as a result of the debugging process used via using alert(id) at the start of the function.

Comment: sounds like there is an issue with whitespace somewhere. Have you tried using trim($image) in the PHP code? and perhaps doing a strtolower or the like and just comparing a lowercase string (maybe the case somewhere is wrong but just overlooked it)

Comment: Humans suck at comparing strings. As @epascarello says, learn to debug. `console.log(id, id === "Sandwich Tins')`. I bet your casing is off.

Answer (score 0):

So you're saying that the alert is returning `"Sandwich Tins"`, and yet the comparison is still failing? If that's the case, then as the others have mentioned there's either:

1) Leading or trailing spaces.

2) Case issues (Although from what you claim that doesn't seem to be the case). No pun intended.

3) "Sandwich Tins" is wrong. Maybe it should be id == "Sandwich Tin"?

Test the first one by doing this:

```
function useUtensil(id) {
    if (id.trim() == "Sandwich Tins") {    
        alert(id);
    } else {
        alert("You do not need that utility!");
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work, try this:

```
function useUtensil(id) {
    if (id.trim().toLowerCase() == "Sandwich Tins".toLowerCase()) {    
        alert(id);
    } else {
        alert("You do not need that utility!");
    }
}
```

If that still doesn't work, I suggest inspecting the input in your console and making sure you're comparing it with the correct string.

Answer (score -4):

put a space 
id ==" Sandwich Tins"